# Good resources for learning pyqt?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt4

I've started learning Python 3 - and now so far that I need some UI to experiment with. I've decided to go with the QT4 IDE (called from the Eric IDE) on Linux. Does anyone know good resources to get started?

Books, tutorials, eBooks - basically anything I can get my hands on :-)

EDIT: Thank you all for your contributions. Sucks, I can't give you all an accepted answer, so I'll choose by the one I found the most helpfull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PyQtWiki has a [Tutorials](http://diotavelli.net/PyQtWiki/Tutorials) page that contains all the best tutorials I've seen on PyQt. In addition, their [start page](http://diotavelli.net/PyQtWiki/StartPage) has links to books, the tutorials, and other resources. Highly recommended.

Answer (score 3):

[Rapid GUI Programming with Python and QT](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Rapid-GUI-Programming-Python-Development/dp/0132354187) by Mark Summerfield is a good book about PyQt4.

AFAIK it uses python 2.x, but I think that's less important. Many people are still using python 2.x, there are lots of libraries that are not ported to python 3.x yet and when python 3.x finally gains traction, there are good chances that this book will be revised to remain actual.

Answer (score 2):

There is the actual [PyQt4 documentation](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/modules.html) and IMHO the much more detailed and clear [PySide documentation](http://www.pyside.org/docs/pyside/) which is still useful as the PySide project is aiming for PyQt4 compatibility thus, for now at least, most of it is applicable to PyQt4.

Comment: I'll be sure to look here :-)